# Regex for excluding characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to strip a string of all special characters except a few, plus remove everything between brackets (square, or any other, Including the brackets!). My current regex is:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ;@.]*$
\\[.+\\]
\\<.+\\>
\\s+
```

All sequences that match one of the above are removed
It works fine on e.g.:

```
Foo Bar[Foo.Bar@google.com]
```

reducing it too `FooBar` but not on e.g.:

```
Foo
foo@bar.com
```

removing them completely

Comment: That regex does not do what you're claiming it does. Please show some actual code/data.

Comment: What must be the result for the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Updating regex as per OP's edit.

You can use the following regex and replace the match with empty string.

```
\[.*?\]|<.*?>|\s|[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ;@.]
```

Comment: @Freek8 updated the answer, for negation of characters you need to keep `^` inside the character set and not outside of it like you are doing currently. `^` outside of character set indicates start of line anchor.

Comment: Thanks Narendra that was indeed the issue (see my comment on lkuty's answer)

Answer (score 1):

To remove anything between brackets except brackets, you could use the following regex and replace it with an empty string:

```
/\[[^\]]*\]/
```

To remove special characters, you could use the one below. It selects everything except what is inside the brackets. So you could once again replace it with the empty string.

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ;@]/
```

You could use them in sequence or build a bigger one.

In Ruby, I have the following test:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "Foo Bar[Foo.Bar@google.com]"
=> "Foo Bar[Foo.Bar@google.com]"
irb(main):005:0* s.gsub(/\[[^\]]*\]|[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ;@]/, "")
=> "FooBar"
```

Note that the space has disappeared.

Comment: I think I fixed it now by using:
    \\[.+\\]
    \\<.+\\>
    [^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ;@.]
    \\s+

I think the problem was the ^ outside the []